# disconnecting HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, disconnect

How can i disconnect an `org.​apache.​http.​client.HttpClient` object?
I'm creating it like this but it doesn't have any `disconnect()` or `getHttpConnectionManager`!

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

[See examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Note: `getHttpConnectionManager` was from HttpClient 3.1.

Comment: Hi Thanks but my HttpClient is 4.1.2 !

Comment: @Snigger: I know, that's what I said.